# Delete sublists of size zero in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Let's say you have a list of lists and that you wish to delete only those lists with the length zero, something like:

```
a={{...},{...},{...},...}
DeleteCases[a, ?]
```

What should the `?` be?

Comment: This question has been asked here at SO before in a slightly more general formulation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562902/efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

may be this:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {}, {5}}
b = DeleteCases[a, x_ /; Length[x] == 0]


{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! (I rarely use mathematica...)

Comment: @Nasser It would quite a bit be more efficient to do `DeleteCases[a, {}]`. E.g. `a = Range /@ RandomInteger[{0, 5}, 10^6];` Then your variant runs in 1.2 seconds, while `DeleteCases[a,{}]` only takes 0.15 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. Mathematica is somewhat complicated because there is always many ways to do the same thing. Finding the correct way to do something can be hard enough, finding the correct and also the most efficient way can be even harder. But it is always interesting to try to find how many ways one can do the same thing in Mathematica.

Answer (score 11):

```
In[1]:= a={{1,2,3},{4,{5,5.5},{}},{},6,f,f[7],{8}}
Out[1]= {{1,2,3},{4,{5,5.5},{}},{},6,f,f[7],{8}}
```

Here's the solution that Nasser provided:

```
In[2]:= DeleteCases[a, x_/;Length[x]==0]
Out[2]= {{1,2,3},{4,{5,5.5},{}},f[7],{8}}
```

Note that it deletes *all* objects of length zero at level 1. If you only want to delete lists of length zero (i.e. `{}`) from the first level then you can use

```
In[3]:= DeleteCases[a, {}]
Out[3]= {{1,2,3},{4,{5,5.5},{}},6,f,f[7],{8}}
```

or if you want to delete them from all levels then use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`)

```
In[4]:= a /. {} -> Sequence[]
Out[4]= {{1,2,3},{4,{5,5.5}},6,f,f[7],{8}}
```

Comment: good point about non-lists items at first level. I did not think about that since the example shown has all lists at first level. But it is good you pointed out this.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. It probably isn't an issue in liberias's problem, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Just beware of `Sequence[]`, [it could swallow you hole](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289605/)

Comment: @belisarius would not that be preferable to being swallowed in half?  (If there is a serious caveat to `Sequence[]` I missed your point.)

Comment: @Mr. That was a joke, of course. Everybody knows that `Sequence[]` is just the sound of one hand clapping.