# How to remove an extra {} in this use of DeleteCases

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

(*Mathematica* version: 8.0.4)

Given

```
lst = {{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}, {{{7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, 13}}};
lst2 = DeleteCases[lst, {x_, y_} /; y > 6, {2}]
```

gives

```
{{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}, {}}
```

Note the extra empty `{}` at the end.

I could not find a way to remove it in the same command using `DeleteCases` (which I think the right command to use for this), so I had to apply it again on the result

```
lst2 = DeleteCases[lst2, {}]

{{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}}
```

**question: Is there a trick to do the above in one command without getting the empty `{}` in the result? so that the command is self contained for all cases?**

**updatet 1**

response to Lou suggestion below, of adding an extra `{ }`

Here is an example where I get different results:

```
lst={{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}, {{{7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, 13}}}
```

now using the method of removing empty `{}` by an extra application of `DeleteCases`, we get

```
lst2 = DeleteCases[lst, {x_, y_} /; y >= 6, {2}]
{{{{1, 2}, 3}}, {}}

lst2 = DeleteCases[lst2, {}]
{{{{1, 2}, 3}}}
```

now using the method of extra `{ }`

```
lst2 = DeleteCases[lst, {{x_, y_}} /; y >= 6]
{{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}}
```

which is the not the same, I should get only `{{{{1, 2}, 3}}}`

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be no general automatic way to remove empty lists which emerge as a result of `DeleteCases` or other structural transformation function, as a part of the original structural operation. Their removal must be a separate operation. This question:

[efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562902/efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists/)

answers how to do that efficiently after the fact

Answer (score 5):

I think that your original solution is a good solution:

```
$lst = {{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}, {{{7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, 13}}};

DeleteCases[$lst, {x_, y_} /; y > 6, {2}] // DeleteCases[#, {}] &
```

It is clear and concise.  An alternative would be this:

```
DeleteCases[$lst, {x_, y_} /; y > 6, {2}] /. {} -> Sequence[]
```

However, let's persevere and try to find a way to do the job with a single invocation of `DeleteCases`.  We could add an alternative pattern that matches top-level elements that contain only rejected subpairs:

```
DeleteCases[
  $lst
, (a:{{_, _?NumericQ}..} /; And @@ Map[#[[2]] > 6 &, a, {1}]) |
  ({_, y_?NumericQ} /; y > 6)
, {1, 2}
]
```

It is inconvenient to write the threshold value (6) twice.  We can avoid that:

```
DeleteCases[
  $lst
, 6 /. n_ :>
    (a:{{_, _?NumericQ}..} /; And @@ Map[#[[2]] > n &, a, {1}]) |
    ({_, y_?NumericQ} /; y > n)
, {1, 2}
]
```

Alternatively, we could define a local function that matches both top-level elements and individual subpairs:

```
Module[{test}
, test[elems:{{_, _?NumericQ}..}] := And @@ test /@ elems
; test[{_List, y_?NumericQ}] := y > 6
; DeleteCases[$lst, e_?test, {1, 2}]
]
```

While these proposals meet the stated requirement to invoke `DeleteCases` only once, I find them unsatisfactory.  My main objection is that they are not as readable as the original solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst2 = DeleteCases[DeleteCases[lst, {x_, y_} /; y > 6, {2}], {}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the above is basically what I did. I wanted to see if one can tell `DeleteCases` not to generate an empty `{}` during the process itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst2 = DeleteCases[lst, {{x_, y_}} /; y > 6]
```

But I suppose you want the first list to be matched to..?
Perhaps:

```
lst2 = DeleteCases[Flatten[lst,1], {x_, y_} /; y >= 6]
```

it results in {{{1, 2}, 3}}

Comment: Thanks, but your method does not work in general. Please see edit (1) showing an example case

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are all very good, and I hesitate to give this reply.

The following is just for fun, nothing more:

```
lst = {{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}, {{{7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, 13}}};
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[lst, {x_, y_} /; ! y > 6, {2}]

Cases[lst, {x_, y_} /; ! y >= 6, {2}]
```

giving

> {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}
>
> {{{1, 2}, 3}}

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an OR clause in DeleteCases and get delete based on the pattern OR a {}

```
DeleteCases[lst, {x_, y_} /; y > 6 | {}, {2} ]
```

On my machine that returns the result:

```
{{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}, {{{7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, 13}}}
```

...which is what I think you wanted.

Comment: thanks, but the answer should come out to be `{{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}}}` your method did nothing to the list.